# Why are async api calls necessary with react-query?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-query

Every piece of documentation shows async calls being used with react-query, but I am a little confused why these are necessary, as the following code works with or without `async/await`:

```
export const apiCall = (method, path, data) => {
    return axios({method, url: API_PREFIX + path, data})
        .then(resp => resp.data)
        .catch(error => {

        });
};

export const useData = () => {
    const {data, isLoading, error, refetch} = useQuery(
        'users',
        async () => await apiCall(dispatch, 'get', '/some-endpoint'),
    );

    return {
        userList: data,
        refetch,
        isLoading
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so that is necessary, `useQuery("users", () => apiCall(dispatch, "get", "/some-endpoint"));` this should also work, I think only expectation here is function should return promise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

react-query wants you to return a resolved or rejected promise - you can produce this however you want. JavaScript has many options to produce promises. async / await is basically just an alternative syntax to promise chaining with `.then` and `.catch`.

The code you've posted also works, however, it also has some unnecessary bits:

`async () => await apiCall(dispatch, 'get', '/some-endpoint'),`

you don't need async / await here, because `apiCall` already returns a Promise, so this would be the same:

`() => apiCall(dispatch, 'get', '/some-endpoint'),`

additionally, I wouldn't `.catch` inside the `apiCall` function, because it would transform failed Promises to successful Promises. With react-query, you'd really want the failed Promise to be returned to react-query so that the library can do the error handling for you. Otherwise, it doesn't know about the error and can't do retries / cannot give you error states etc.

so for `apiCall`, these two things would also be equivalent and would work nicely with react-query:

```
export const apiCall = (method, path, data) => {
    return axios({method, url: API_PREFIX + path, data})
        .then(resp => resp.data)
};
```

```
export const apiCall = async (method, path, data) => {
    const response = await axios({method, url: API_PREFIX + path, data})
    return respons.data
};
```

this really just depends on which syntax you like more - most people prefer async / await because it avoids excessive callback chains.

I've written a somewhat comprehensive blog post about this topic as well: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/about-async-functions

Comment: Thank you, this is awesome. Helps me understand much better.